# wordpress: set class of navigation element to content of element

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

i'm new to wordpress theming and I currently try to implement a navigation menu using icons. The framework i use requires me to set specific class names to achieve the icon being displayed - so what i basically want is:

```
<ul>
   <li class="blog">blog</li>
   ....
```

So the class should be equal to the content

I found the following in the wordpress docs

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if(is_single() && $item->title == "Blog"){
        $classes[] = "special-class";
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

This is how I currently display my menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) );
```

I'm kind of confused by the example given from the wordpress doc's since I cannot figure out the use of al the parameters or even where to place it.

Comment: In Appearance > Menus page, in the right upper corner, there is a Screen options button. Click it and enable css classes, and whatever you want. Then you can add what ever class you want. My guess is that you can add your icon name class there.

Comment: thx - but I think this will only allow me to add ONE specific class for all my navigation menu items. What I want is a different class for each item...

Comment: No, this adds css input field to each menu item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are registered your primary menu in `functions.php`.

After that you must put this code sample again in your `functions.php`.

What the code does is that it would launch the function `special_nav_class` for each menu item from `primary-menu`. As a parameter this function will receive the current menu item ( as post object ) and current classes applied for it as an array.

So, if you have menu with 5 elements, this function will run 5 times and each time it will receive current menu item and its classes array.

Basically something like this can do the job, if menu items are named properly:

```
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    $classes[] = strtolower($item->title);
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: thx a lot, can you just briefly explain what the paramters of the add filter class are for?

Comment: Filters in WP are designed to modify data, so they must recieve this data, modifying it and then return it. 
The second parameter in add_filter hook is the number of arguments the function accept. Default is 1, so if you don't put here 2, you will not receive the second parameter $item in this case.

The first parameter specify the order in which the functions are executed.

Comment: this is working for me ! thx! last question what is the 10 for :) ?

Comment: The first parameter specify the order in which the functions are executed. If you have 2 functions in one hook the lower number will run early.